# Get the next datetime value

Tags: mysql, query, mariadb-10.3

I have a MySQL table:

```
SELECT 
    sh.id,
    sh.DG_ID,
    sh.START_DATE
FROM 
    STATUS_HISTORIES sh
order by DG_ID, START_DATE
```

| id | DG_ID | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 212 | 2021-04-20 14:59:58 |
| 66 | 212 | 2021-04-21 05:01:25 |
| 110 | 212 | 2021-04-21 14:58:31 |
| 157 | 212 | 2021-04-22 05:00:40 |

I want to get next datetime value or null if next datetime value doesn't exist. Like this:

| id | DG_ID | START_DATE | next_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 212 | 2021-04-20 14:59:58 | 2021-04-21 05:01:25 |
| 66 | 212 | 2021-04-21 05:01:25 | 2021-04-21 14:58:31 |
| 110 | 212 | 2021-04-21 14:58:31 | 2021-04-22 05:00:40 |
| 157 | 212 | 2021-04-22 05:00:40 | NUll |

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT 
    sh.id,
    sh.DG_ID,
    sh.START_DATE,
    sh2.START_DATE as next_start_date
FROM 
    STATUS_HISTORIES sh
    left join STATUS_HISTORIES sh2 on sh2.id = sh.id and sh2.START_DATE > sh.START_DATE 
order by sh.DG_ID, sh.START_DATE
```

but got null:

| id | DG_ID | START_DATE | next_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 212 | 2021-04-20 14:59:58 | null |
| 66 | 212 | 2021-04-21 05:01:25 | null |
| 110 | 212 | 2021-04-21 14:58:31 | null |
| 157 | 212 | 2021-04-22 05:00:40 | null |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD` window function in MariaDB 10.2+, MySQL version 8.0+, and SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT 
    sh.id,
    sh.DG_ID,
    sh.START_DATE,
    LEAD(sh.START_DATE) OVER (
        PARTITION BY sh.DG_ID ORDER BY sh.START_DATE) as next_start_date
FROM 
    STATUS_HISTORIES sh
ORDER BY sh.DG_ID, sh.START_DATE
```